# Select a webview using applescript in an application

Tags: applescript, wkwebview

I'm using Applescript to open an application, said application has a webview. I'm trying to select only the webview. Structure of the application appears below.  The "Hello" portion is the webview I want to select. I was trying 'UI element 9' but it appears sometimes the app opens and re-orders the controls. In the below iamge, I want the control whose text is 'Hello', which is a WebView.

[image]

I would like in the following script to know how to replace `UI element 9` with `web view 1` or something similar. I just don't know the way to target the webview element.

```
set i to scroll area 1 of UI element 9 of splitter group 1 of the front window
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking for Applescript dictionary, I can't find 'web view', but only following UI elements :

browsers, busy indicators, buttons, checkboxes, color wells, columns, combo boxes, drawers, groups, grow areas, images, incrementors, lists, menus, menu bars, menu bar items, menu buttons, menu items, outlines, pop overs, pop up buttons, progress indicators, radio buttons, radio groups, relevance indicators, rows, scroll areas, scroll bars, sheets, sliders, splitters, splitter groups, static texts, tab groups, tables, text areas, text fields, toolbars, UI elements, value indicators, windows.

You can also call/refer to UI element by its name (if any) like :

```
click menu "File" of menu bar 1
```

instead of

```
click menu 3 of menu bar 1
```

(third menu is usually File menu, after "Apple" and "application")
However, it could be that your application did not defined a name for the relevant UI Element, then only index can be used !